# Turn off automatic macOS updates

Tags: macos, mac, software-update, preferences

I'm trying to turn off automatic macOS updates. When I run command:

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate AutomaticDownload -boolean FALSE
```

it works:

```
$ defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate AutomaticDownload -boolean                                                                                           
0
```

[image]

But after reboot my changes are being reverted:

[image]

I even created custom preference file in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist`, but it didn't help. Why my changes keep reverting?

Comment: Does the checkbox in the UI not work for you? Why are you doing this on the command line?

Comment: Was this computer previously managed by an organization?

Comment: @Ezekiel yes, it was and this behaviour is some leftover I cannot identify :(

Comment: I'd strongly recommend clean installing macOS if it was once managed by organization before using it privately. (if you're using it privately, ofcourse.)

Comment: I agree with Skye-AT here. You should wipe the machine and transfer your data manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by using great software [KnockKnock](https://objective-see.com/products/knockknock.html) to track down Launch Agents/Daemons

[image]

and then disabling them by simply renaming, for example:

```
sudo mv /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.<some item>.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.<some item>.plist.bak
```